# Connect to SQL Server Database using jdbc Java, Android app

Tags: java, android, jdbc

Can you help me, please?
I'm trying to create an Android app, which will connect to SQL Server Database. 
I'm using JDBC driver and:

1. Added JDBC in Projects Setting -> Library (shown in External Libraries)
2. The code of connecting to DB is as follows:

   ```
   try {
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.x.x.x:yyyy;integratedSecurity=true;"
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
       if (con != null) {
           tv.setText("Connected");
       } else {
           tv.setText("Not connected");
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       tv.setText("" + ex);
   }
   ```

Eventually, I receive an Exception, that Driver `com.microsoft.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` not found

If I run the same Console app on Java app, it works.

Comment: did you install SQL Server Database in your android?wow

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851938/equivalent-jdbc-connection-string-for-sql-server

Comment: No. Actually, I plan Android app to connect to a SQL Server, that is on my home computer

Comment: then you dont need driver in your android app, just make a web service

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is add rest api at home server and use on phone to connect and exchange data. Its not enterprise java and it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! The trouble was, I didn't add jdbc library in the project properly. The next problem I faced is that network connection goes via main thread. So I need to create a separate thread for SQL Server connection